# Python SQLite3 - Does it BEGIN, END transaction on each insert statement?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to optimize my SQLite3 inserts as I am working on some large data set.

**What I am wondering is if the .execute("INSERT...") statements BEGIN and END a transaction for each execute statement? Or does it simply execute a BEGIN on the first execute, and it waits for the .commit() operation, hence I can do 10,000 .execute commands and then do .commit(), hence I only did one transaction?**

I am not very clear on that side of the story and I would really appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQLite Optimization FAQ[1]:

> Unless already in a transaction, each SQL statement has a new
>   transaction started for it.  This is very expensive, since it requires
>   reopening, writing to, and closing the journal file for each
>   statement. This can be avoided by wrapping sequences of SQL statements
>   with BEGIN TRANSACTION; and END TRANSACTION; statements. This speedup
>   is also obtained for statements which don't alter the database.

So, there are two ways:

1. Use executemany() method.
2. Use explicit `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statement.

[1] http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html

Comment: This is not correct when using the Python `sqlite3` module.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions) says:

> By default, the **sqlite3** module opens transactions implicitly before a Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e. `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`/`REPLACE`), and commits transactions implicitly before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than `SELECT` or the aforementioned).